# PyMongo kwargs in URI

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Consider the signature for the `pymongo.MongoClient` class: `pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient(host='localhost', port=27017, document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, **kwargs)` which accepts arbitrary keyword arguments (`**kwargs`).

According to the [`PyMongo` documenation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient), one of these keyword args is `serverSelectionTimeoutMS`. According to the [`MongoDB` documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/), I can pass this argument in the URI of the connection string.

If I pass this argument to the `URI` into `MongoClient`, does it have the same effect as if I pass as a keyword argument? For example, is

`MongoClient(host='mongodb://localhost?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=45000')`

the same as

`MongoClient(host='localhost', serverSelectionTimeoutMS=45000)`

?

I can't quite tell from the `PyMongo` source code. Using `PyMongo==3.6.1` and `MongoDB==3.4`.

Comment: yes, both will set the serverSelectionTimeoutMS parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

The options parsed from the database URI are set as the [client options](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.1/pymongo/mongo_client.py#L473).

```
res = uri_parser.parse_uri(entity, port, warn=True)
...
opts = res["options"]
```

However, [keyword options take precedence](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.1/pymongo/mongo_client.py#L496).

```
 keyword_opts = kwargs
 ...

 opts.update(keyword_opts)
```

The [client options created](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.6.1/pymongo/mongo_client.py#L507) is used to create the topology settings.

```
self.__options = options = ClientOptions(
    username, password, dbase, opts)
```